# increment array index left side of assignment operator

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, operator-keyword, unary-operator

```
int[] array = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3 };
int i = 1;
array[i++] = array[i]+5;
   
var result = string.Join(",", array);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

can you explain how to work 3rd row? I mean why the answer is 1,8,3

Comment: `i++` means use the value of `i` and then add one to it so the next time it gets used, will be a new value. So the value in array index 1 gets set to the value of array index 2 + 5.

Comment: so the order is like that right ? =>1) set the index value(which is i=1) , 2) increment i value (i=2), 3) add 5 to array[2] =8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be translated to:

```
int[] array = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3 };
int i = 1;
array[1] = array[2]+5;
```

because `i++` means: use the old value of `i` and afterwards increment it by 1. So at the assignment `array[i]+5`, `i` will have the new value 2.

If you instead use `++i` instead it will "translate" to:

```
array[2] = array[2]+5;
```

because `++i` means: increment it before you use it.

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation